# Create a variable whose values are with data type array and those values came from multiple columns

Tags: arrays, r, split-apply-combine

I would like to know how I could come up with the new variable "test_array" which is of data type array and created by combining columns "test_1" to "test_4" because I wanted to use it for further calculations.

```
id    test_1    test_2    test_3    test_4    test_array
1        10      20       30         40         [10,20,30,40]
2                 3       10         20         [ , 3, 10,20]
3         58      98                            [58,98,  ,  ]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiuUv.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option using `tidyr::nest` to nest data by `id`. The result is a new column `data` containing a `list` of `tibble`s.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% left_join(df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    nest())
#  id test_1 test_2 test_3 test_4           data
#1  1     10     20     30     40 10, 20, 30, 40
#2  2     NA      3     10     20  NA, 3, 10, 20
#3  3     58     98     NA     NA 58, 98, NA, NA
```

---

### Sample

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "id    test_1    test_2    test_3    test_4
1        10      20       30         40
2      ''           3       10         20
3         58      98        ''    ''", header = T)
```

---

### Update

To calculate the maximum of every element in `data` you can do

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(max = map_dbl(data, ~max(.x, na.rm = T)))
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#     id data               max
#  <int> <list>           <dbl>
#1     1 <tibble [1 × 4]>   40.
#2     2 <tibble [1 × 4]>   20.
#3     3 <tibble [1 × 4]>   98.
```

Comment: @zx8754 Good point:-) If `id` is not unique, I would use `rowid_to_column("row")` to create unique rows and then `group_by(row)` instead. But your solution is more concise +1.

Comment: Can I use the "data" column for calculation? In my final data set I will just keep the "data" and id columns and perform several loopings and calculations such as lags, averages,max, min,etc. For example, I wanted to use value of test_4 only from the "data" column multiplied by 20% and assigned to new variable "new_test_4"?

Comment: @Ashtasora If you only want to keep `data` and `id` the code becomes even shorter because you don't need to `left_join` anymore. I've added an example how to use `data` in calculating the max.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Can I use the "data" column for calculation? In my final data set I will just keep the "data" and id columns and perform several loopings and calculations such as lags, averages,max, min,etc. For example, I wanted to use value of test_4 only from the "data" column multiplied by 20% and assigned to new variable "new_test_4"?

Comment: @Ashtasora ?? Did you not see my update? The answer is, yes of course. `data` is a `list` of `tibble`s. I demonstrate in my update how to use `data` to return the maximum of every element per row. You can easily adjust this to your needs.

Comment: @MauritsEvers,just thinking if I can use nest() multiple times in one block of code to create variable? I tried it but it seems not working...

Comment: @Ashtasora I'm not sure what you mean by using `nest` *"multiple times in one block of code to create variable"*. In general, you can have nested lists inside a `tibble`; whether that's useful is a different question and depends on your problem statement. If you open a new question with a code example and what you'd like to do I'm happy to take a look.

Comment: What I'm just doing is to perform left_join to build the data.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, this is noted. I will write my code and post or open a new question. Thank you

Comment: @Ashtasora Not sure what `left_join`ing has to do with `nest`ing. `nest` creates a `list` of `data.frame`s/`tibble`s inside another `data.frame`/`tibble`. You can definitely `nest` two `data.frame`s and then join them on a common column. If you post a link to your new question here, I'll have a look.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, could you please help me understand how the map_dbl() works? Because I wanted to perform subtraction, instead. I was able to create variables "StartHireDate"  and "EndHireDate" using the nest() and left_join both of which have list data types with Dates as values. And so I need to calculate "YrsEmployed"="EndHireDate"-"StartHireDate". Can I do it with the same data type or there's a much better way? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

```
# example data
df1 <- mtcars[1:3, 1:4]

df1$test_array <- lapply(data.frame(t(df1)), as.numeric)
#                mpg cyl disp  hp             test_array
# Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110        21, 6, 160, 110
# Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110        21, 6, 160, 110
# Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 22.8, 4.0, 108.0, 93.0
```

Comment: lapply gave me a value with "c" at the beginning like c(1,10,20,30,40). I just wanted the values from test_1 to test_4 excluding the id, and yet I still wanted that the "id" column" in my data set because it is my primary key. And can I use the "test_array" result of lappy for calculation?

Comment: lapply gave me a value with "c" at the beginning like c(1,10,20,30,40). I just wanted the values from test_1 to test_4 excluding the id, and yet I still wanted that the "id" column" in my data set because it is my primary key. And can I use the "test_array" result of lappy for calculation?@zx8754

Answer (score 0):

Using `within`:

```
within(df,  test_array <- paste(test_1, test_2, test_3, test_4, sep=","))
```

Output:

```
 id test_1 test_2 test_3 test_4  test_array
 1  1     10     20     30     40 10,20,30,40
 2  2     NA      3     10     20  NA,3,10,20
 3  3     58     98     NA     NA 58,98,NA,NA
```

Comment: test_array data type is character. Can I use it for calculation?

Comment: @Ashtasora: Yes it is a character. What kind of computation do you want? When you combine multiple columns you mostly have a character.